# How to restrict user to enter date manually in date field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on an application in which i want to restrict user to manually enter the date in the type=date field in html page.
I want to restrict the user to select the date only from the calender display which is MM/DD/YYYY.

Below is the code in html page :

```js
 <input type="date" name="bankTrans" ng-model="orderAstro.paymentDate" 
        class="form-control" id="bankTrans"
        ng-disabled="isDisabled" required />
```

Also attaching the image for error clarity :
[Image for error clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snWJc.png)

[image]

Comment: If this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56785250/11572405 answer worked for you then kindly, accept this answer by clicking Tick and also Up Arrow button in front of my answer...Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

use following line of code to restrict manual date field entry using jquery.

```
$("input[type='date']").keydown(function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1:**

Your question makes sense.

The best way to work with a date is to disable manual entry and allow changes only using the **Date Picker**.

**Add a 'readonly' attribute to the input field:**

```
<input type="date" readonly name="bankTrans" 
ng-model="orderAstro.paymentDate" class="form-control" 
id="bankTrans" ng-disabled="isDisabled" required />
```

Do you want the code for above Angular js file and HTML as well or this much is fine.

Comment: How datepicker can be insert here in this case

Comment: Did this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56785250/11572405 "Edit 2" post solved your Problems? If Yes, Kindly tick "Edit 2" answer and also up arrow it...Thank You...@Roopam Gupta

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this, is not solving the issue, as intended.

This might help: https://jsdaddy.github.io/ngx-mask-page/main#prefix

```
<input mask="00/00/0000">
```

Comment: How this is going to restrict user to enter manually? as it used for formatting purpose

Comment: Yes cant enter manually but even not able to see calender for selection now

Comment: In that case pls edit ur question with that calendar information as well.

Comment: Sorry for confusion but i mentioned it in the question : "I want to restrict the user to select the date only from the calender display which is MM/DD/YYYY."

Comment: which is that calendar, that should also be there right?

Comment: For selecting the date we are using "type=date" which generates one calender but we are able to manually enter the date so for that i raised the concerns

Comment: ok, right, that will differently on all browser, might not work in safari, then use some datepicker, as explained by @vinod. In some u might just disable input and use a separate button to launch datepicker

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2:**

Disabling the manual Entry of Date and allowing only through Date Picker.

**HTML code:**

```
<input type="text" readonly class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{clCtrl.format}}"
 ng-model="clCtrl.QualityExpirationDate" is-open="clCtrl.openedQualityDate" 
 min-date="clCtrl.minDate" datepicker-options="clCtrl.dateOptions" 
 ng-required="true" close-on-date-selection="true" 
 show-button-bar="false" />
```

**js file:**

```
$scope.$watch('dt', function(val) {
    $scope.isValidDate =  isNaN(new Date(val).getTime());
});

self.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
};

self.formats = ['MM-dd-yyyy', 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'MM.dd.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
self.format = self.formats[0]; 

self.openQualityDate = function ($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    self.openedQualityDate = true;
};


self.toggleMin = function () {
    self.minDate = self.minDate ? null : new Date();
};
self.toggleMin();

self.clear = function () {

    self.QualityExpirationDate = null;
};
```

Comment: @Roopam Gupta If this answer worked for you then kindly, accept this answer by clicking Tick and also Up Arrow button in front of my answer...Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me!

added the following attributes to my date type input tags.

```
<input type="date" name="dob" "minlength": "10", "maxlength": "10", class="form-control" />
```